# How can I test if a permutation hypothesis test produces valid results based on the probability distribution used?

Tags: distributions, p-value, autocorrelation, truncated-normal-distribution

I'm using the Join Count statistics to get insight if there is spatial autocorrelation in a categorical feature. I would like to test if the pseudo p-value returned comes from a valid hypothesis test based on the probability distribution it occurs on.

It is a **pseudo** p-value because it assumes normality in the distribution, which is not always the case. Being the result of several (999, usually) permutations of the data, the distribution can take other forms that are not gaussian.

My unfounded assumption (and the reason of this question) is that I can't consider the p-value valid if the distribution is uniform, or if it consists of a single value (both cases happen when the analysed variable occurs rarely).

Based on that, I started running a Shapiro-Wilk test on the distributions resulted by the analysis. But, when looking graphically at the ones the test was discarding, I realized several are truncated normal distributions (which I would consider valid).

Realizing that the permutations could produce different sorts of distributions, it seemed reasonable to question how to analyse them and to gain knowledge on which distributions allow valid hypothesis tests.

> **What is (or how can I determine) the robustness of the Join Count test for departures from Normality?**

## Contextualization of Join Count statistics (if needed)

*I believe experience with the method I'm trying to use is not needed to help me, so I will try to contextualize it briefly.*

The analysis looks at the original distribution of my data, counting how many elements neighbor someone with the same value (black-black connection, or **BB**) and how many neighbor someone with a different value (black-white connection, or **BW**). Then, it permutates my data several times, doing the same counts.

A one-tailed hypothesis test is then made considering the distribution of values encountered and the measurement for the original data. The pseudo p-value for positive autocorrelation is the placement of the original BB count in the BB distribution, and for negative autocorrelation it considers the BW count in the BW distribution.

### An example

Consider a binary variable that occurs on points that are distributed in space.

[image: Original data distribution]

I determine that the neighbors of a point are the K points nearest to it. BB and BW connections are counted based on points of value 1 and their neighbors. In this case, the BB count will be high and the BW count will be low (BW connections only happen in the border between orange and blue).

The method now permutates the variable value for the data, maintaining both the position of the points and the proportion between 1 and 0 occurances.

[image: Random permutation of the data]

New BB and BW counts are evaluated, resulting in close values, as their occurances are the same.

A permutation happens again, followed by another count, until N (999) values are gathered. Then, the BB counts are sorted and the original BB count position is the pseudo p-value of the test.

In this case, the original BB count is the highest between all permutations, resulting in 0.999 confidence in rejecting the hypothesis of no positive autocorrelation. Meanwhile, the original BW count is the lowest, resulting in 0.000 confidence in rejecting the hypothesis of no negative autocorrelation.

[image: Permutation distribution and original value]

Therefore, a valid conclusion is that this variable has a positive spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "testing" a distribution and by a "distribution that produces a pseudo p-value"?  The former is mysterious and the latter is puzzling because distributions don't produce p-values: only null hypothesis tests produce p-values.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber , I hope I can add to the community. Could you help me with the right phrasing? By "testing" I meant like a Shapiro-Wilk test, that gives insight about a distribution; and by the "distribution that produces..." I meant the distribution over which a null hypothesis test is made, this test producing the p-value. The way the test I'm using works, it always returns a [pseudo] p-value, regardless of the shape of the distribution. I want a way to validate this test by looking at the distribution used on it.

Comment: That's becoming clearer, thank you.  It sounds like you want to investigate the *robustness* of the join count test to *departures from Normality.*

Comment: "Robustness of the join count test to departures from normality" sounds like the question that will solve the universe. Thank you very much, I will edit my question to make it clearer. To you think the contextualization I did helps at all?